# Powershell: copy-item deletes file

Tags: powershell, copy-item

I have a client that removes/writes files every 10 seconds on my laptop. I also have a Powershell script that is supposed to copy files whenever they are changed, to a network location.

Now to the problem: sometimes, quite often, one or two of the files on the remote network location gets deleted. But I have nothing in the script that is supposed to delete any file, only copy.

How come this happens? See the script below:

```
$block = {
function CreateCopyFile
{
    param ($message, $event)
    # function to call when event is raised
    # do a robocopy or whatever

    $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
    $targetpath = $targetFolder + "/" + $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name

    Copy-Item $path $targetFolder
}


$watchedFolder = "C:\Users\test\Documents\folder"
$targetFolder = "\\TRICASTER-MINI\DataLink Watch Folder"
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = $watchedFolder

Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $watcher -EventName Created -SourceIdentifier File.Created -Action { CreateCopyFile "Created" $event }
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $watcher -EventName Changed -SourceIdentifier File.Changed -Action { CreateCopyFile "Changed" $event }
}

$encodedBlock = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($block))

Start-Process PowerShell.exe -verb Runas -argumentlist '-WindowStyle Hidden', '-NoExit', '-EncodedCommand', $encodedBlock
```

Comment: Any idea the filetype of the files being deleted? The aren't temp files are they?

Comment: The files that are being deleted are the destination files. That is, the xml files that are supposed to be replaced with the new file with Copy-item.

We also tried to first copy to a local temp folder and from there to the remote. But same issue. It's as if the script either conflicts with the files being deleted/created or that too much is happening. But the files are very small.

Comment: You could try [SysInternals' Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/processmonitor) and watch what happens. I tried it on a basic copy-item and there's no obvious call to delete anything. Do you actually mean the destination is gone? Or do you mean it's there but 0Kb empty? I imagine the former, but it's easier to think of possible explanations for the latter ;)

Comment: Can you clarify what files are being deleted?